# How to import *huge* chunks of data to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
Model Place
    primary key "id"

    foreign key "parent" -> Place
    foreign key "neighbor" -> Place (symmetryc)
    foreign key "belongtos" -> Place (asymmetric)

    a bunch of scalar fields ...
```

I have over 5 million rows in the model table, and I need to insert **~50 million** rows into each of the two foreign key tables. I have `SQL` files that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO place_belongtos (from_place_id, to_place_id) VALUES (123, 456);
```

and they are about **7 Gb** each. The problem is, when I do `psql < belongtos.sql`, it takes me about **12 hours** to import **~4 million** rows on my AMD Turion64x2 CPU. OS is Gentoo ~amd64, PostgreSQL is version 8.4, compiled locally. The data dir is a bind mount, located on my second extended partition (`ext4`), which I believe is not the bottleneck.

I'm suspecting it takes so long to insert the foreign key relations because `psql` checks for the key constraints for each row, which probably adds some unnecessary overhead, as I know for sure that the data is valid. Is there a way to speed up the import, i.e. temporarily disabling the constraint check?

Comment: yes but I think it's only in 8.4+ hmm have to look it up....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Make sure both foreign key constraints are [DEFERRABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)
2. Use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) to load your data
3. If you can't use COPY, use a [prepared statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) for your INSERT.
4. Propper configuration settings will also help, check the [WAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html) settings.

Comment: +1 for COPY, makes a huge difference on DBs I run across that insert tons of data regularly...

Comment: I already use DEFERRABLE. COPY is the thing that I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Using deferrable is one thing, realy using this option is another thing: INITIALLY DEFERRED or SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

Comment: It might even make sense to drop indexes, constraints, and triggers, and then rebuild them after the import is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes... [Depesz wrote an article here on deferrable uniqueness](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2009/08/11/waiting-for-8-5-deferrable-uniqueness/). unfortunately it seems to be a 9.0 feature.

hmm... Maybe that article doesn't apply to your situation? Seems we've been able to [set constraints to deferred](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) for a while... I'm guessing that unique is a unique situation (pun intended).

Comment: Foreign keys are already deferrable in older versions, no problem.

Comment: The article from Depesz describes to deferrable *unique* constraints (e.g. a primary key) which were not deferreable before 9.0 e.g. to run UPDATE id = id + 1 (where id is a PK column)
Regular FK constraints have "always" been deferrable. 
Setting the constraint to deferrable won't prevent the checking, it will only _delay_ the checking to the end of the transaction (i.e. when commit is executed)