# What is an efficient method to import a database into Django/Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am working on a project using Django and Postgres.The previous version was done using other technology.

How can I migrate the previous version to Django?  The data is very large, so speed of import is critical.

Since both database schemas are complex, I don't think it is feasible to directly use Postgres.  If I use Django is there an alternative to creating (complex) objects?

Answer (score 0):

You could use default PostgreSQL backup mechanism
Or you can use Django ORM built in (which is slower but not tied to DB type)
`./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json`
`./manage.py loaddata db.json`
And check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437608/5751147)

Comment: I suspect the database structure is very different in the two systems, so not sure if I can use the backup mechanism.

Comment: It is using ORM, so yes you can use them if two of your databases are supporting Django ORM

Comment: ORM will be too slow